# unable to write unittest for gin web framework golang

Tags: go

I have written below code to test a function

```
func TestServe(t *testing.T) {
        config.SetLoggerConfig("logger.apipath")
        router := Serve()

        w := httptest.NewRecorder()
        req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "/nodes", nil)
        router.ServeHTTP(w, req)

        assert.Equal(t, 200, w.Code)
}
```

here Server() returns a gin engine
when i run this ,the code gets stuck at

[GIN-debug] Listening and serving HTTP on :8080

How to get around this?

I have modified the code but it still hangs below are snippets

server.go snippet

```
func Serve() *gin.Engine {
        logger.Log.Info("Serve()")

        r := gin.Default()
        r.GET("/ping", func(c *gin.Context) {
                c.JSON(200, gin.H{
                        "message": "pong",
                })
        })
        r.Use(ginzap.Ginzap(logger.Log, time.RFC3339, false))
        r.Use(ginzap.RecoveryWithZap(logger.Log, true))

        r.GET("/nodes", listNodes)
        r.POST("/uuid", getUUID)
        r.GET("/hwstatus/:node_id", getNodeHWStatus)
        r.PUT("/hwstatus/:node_id", updateNodeHWStatus)
        node := r.Group("/node")
        {
                node.POST("/", createNode)
                node.GET("/:node_id", describeNode)
                node.PUT("/:node_id", updateNode)
                node.DELETE("/:node_id", deleteNode)
                node.POST("/deploy/:node_id", deployNode)
        }

        if err := r.Run(":8080"); err != nil {
                logger.Log.Fatal("Failed to Run Server", zap.Error(err))
                //log.Fatalf("Failed to Run server: %v ", err)
        }
        return r
}
```

testing.go snippet is as below

```
func TestDescribeNode(t *testing.T) {
        config.SetLoggerConfig("logger.apipath")
        ts := httptest.NewServer(Serve())
        defer ts.Close()
        resp, err := http.Get(fmt.Sprintf("%s/node/12334", ts.URL))
       if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("Expected no error, got %v", err)
    }

    if resp.StatusCode != 200 {
        t.Fatalf("Expected status code 200, got %v", resp.StatusCode)
    }
```

Comment: find a way to eliminate `Serve()` line from your code.

Comment: how would i test if server() is not called , Serve() serves the content which is used in calling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Run` (`r.Run(":8080")` that you've called from `Serve()`) does attach the router to a `http.Server` and starts listening and serving HTTP requests. It is a shortcut for `http.ListenAndServe(addr, router)`. It blocks the caller indefinitely unless an error happens.

You've to take out `r.Run(":8080")` from `Serve()` if you want to use `Serve()` to create the test server like this `httptest.NewServer(Serve())`. For example, you can modify your code something like this:

```
func Serve() *gin.Engine {
    logger.Log.Info("Serve()")

    r := gin.Default()
    r.GET("/ping", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.JSON(200, gin.H{
            "message": "pong",
        })
    })
    r.Use(ginzap.Ginzap(logger.Log, time.RFC3339, false))
    r.Use(ginzap.RecoveryWithZap(logger.Log, true))

    r.GET("/nodes", listNodes)
    r.POST("/uuid", getUUID)
    r.GET("/hwstatus/:node_id", getNodeHWStatus)
    r.PUT("/hwstatus/:node_id", updateNodeHWStatus)
    node := r.Group("/node")
    {
        node.POST("/", createNode)
        node.GET("/:node_id", describeNode)
        node.PUT("/:node_id", updateNode)
        node.DELETE("/:node_id", deleteNode)
        node.POST("/deploy/:node_id", deployNode)
    }
    return r
}

func Start() {
    if err := Serve().Run(":8080"); err != nil {
        logger.Log.Fatal("Failed to Run Server", zap.Error(err))
        //log.Fatalf("Failed to Run server: %v ", err)
    }
}
```

Comment: i have tried this approach also , there is a serve() function and there is describenode() function in server.go and in the test file i have called in same way but it hangs and says listening.cannot paste the whole code in comment due to word limits

Comment: Have you tried injecting *gin.Engine returned from serve() into httptest.NewServer? Like this: ts := httptest.NewServer(serve())

Comment: i have written it like this
        config.SetLoggerConfig("logger.apipath")
        ts := httptest.NewServer(Serve())
        defer ts.Close()
        resp, err := http.Get(fmt.Sprintf("%s/node/12334", ts.URL))

Comment: I have edited the question with latest code but it still hangs

Comment: @user3129322 Updated the answer with modifying your code. Good luck!

Comment: hey sarath, i figured this out yesterday by comparing my code to your code and this was only difference but still not able to understand why it would behave that way when called in separate func ,any article u have for better understanding gin ?

Comment: Because, Run() blocks the caller indefinitely unless an error happens. You can refer the doc and code from Github https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin